# Need to know if there is a program that will search for all sub-folders given a specific web address

Tags: search, webaddress

I am working on a project at work where we currently have a very labor intensive process of looking for verification of certain documents having been uploaded to a folder. My bosses would like me to automate this process to save time. I have found where this can be done for computer directories, but haven't been able to find it for web addresses.

I tried searching for the type of search algorithm I'm looking for, but found one that works for computer directories, not web addresses.

Comment: "web crawlers" and "scraping" can find links on pages and follow them recursively.  If there are no links, the files can't be found.     Anything else is going to depend on the context - Sharepoint, OneNote, DropBox, etc. may have discovery APIs you can write code for but each is platform-specific.  You should edit this to add much more details about the environment, or do some searches on whatever it is for existing tools.

Comment: You might also want to search on "document management system" and look for something with tracking, logging, versioning, access control, user roles, etc.